# Is there a Excel/Googlesheets function that assigns a value to a specific word?

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a Google Sheet with all Social Media Posts of a specific account. One Colume has the Timing of the Posts (How long ago was this posted: e.g. 1 Day, 5 Days, 3 Hrs., 3 Months...). I want to assign a score to each timing to give a general score for Posting frequency. For Example, 5 points for each Score that was posted X hrs. ago, 3 Points for each score that was Posted Day/Days ago, ...

Is it possible to create a function that lets me assign a Value to a Specific Word (like Day/Days or Month/Months), so that I can Average them?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Yes, it is possible. However, right now, we have no specifics of your spreadsheet, layout, ranges or data. As player0 suggests, the most efficient way to share all the details at once is to share a link to a sample spreadsheet containing realistic sample data and your expected results where you want to see them. You should also include this information in written or visual form within your post.